# Re-Sign unsigned ipa using AirSign issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipa, unsigned

I am using AirSign to sign an unsigned ipa.
Under Code Signing tab->Re-Signing configuration->Provisioning Profile NONE is the only option available and I am not able to select any provisioning profile. "CodeSign Application" option is disabled.
Anyone who has worked on this and faced same issue?